# Prove that $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3})$ is a PID.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

While self-studying algebraic number theory, I came across the following problem:

> Prove that $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3})$ is a PID.

where $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3})$ denotes the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3})$.  My first intuition was to find the Minkowski bound and hope that it's below $2$, but this turns out to not be the case.  Let $R := \mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3})$; then we know that $|\text{disc}(R)| = 16\cdot2\cdot3\cdot6$, so the Minkowski bound is $$ \frac{4!}{4^4}\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^2\sqrt{16\cdot 6 \cdot 3 \cdot 2} \approx 3.64. $$

Thus, I need only show that the primes lying over $2$ and $3$ are principally generated, but I'm having trouble showing that.  I don't (in general) know how  primes split in this ring, so I tried to use the different.  We know that $\| \text{diff}(R) \| = |\text{disc}(R)| = 2^6\cdot 3^2$, so we can conclude $$(3) = (\frak{p}_3\frak{p}_3')^2. $$

I'm not sure how this helps, though.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The prime $3$ is inert in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so $f_3 = 2$ and $e_3 = 2$, hence $(3) = \mathfrak{p}^2_3$. But then one can see that $\mathfrak{p}_3 = (\sqrt{-3})$. Similarly, $2$ is inert in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, and so $(2) = \mathfrak{p}^2_2$ where $\mathfrak{p}_2 = (\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Given the powerful contemporary precedent that, in a number theory context, $\mathbb A$ is the adeles of a number field, it might be less jarring to use a different symbol. A mathfrak "o" is more typical (as silly as that might seem): $\mathfrak o$ or $\mathfrak O$.